# Why do I keep getting the c++ error: exit status 1 main.cpp:5:1: error: 'name' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I keep on getting the same error:
exit status 1
main.cpp:5:1: error: 'name' does not name a type
 name[0] = "hello";
 ^~~~
I do not understand why?
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string name[5];

name[0] = "hello";

int main() {
... other stuff ...
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and made the question named wrong, how do I rename the question?

Comment: See the "edit" link?

Comment: You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign variables in external scope.

Move this line to inside `main()`:

```
name[0] = "hello";
```

Assigning is different from initializing.

Comment: Good answer but you should add an option of declare and initialize global variable. What I am trying to say that he could do 'std::string name[5] = "hello";` outside of the `main()` and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign name in external of main(). Then you cant assigning like this "name[0] = "hello"" but you can use

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> 
Using namespace std;
Void main(){
char name[100];
strcpy(name,"hello");
}
```

Comment: Why `[100]` when  `5` is enough.. simple `char name[5]="hello";` will do

Comment: 100 is max word which i usually use but if you want 5, it is okay